# Why is my else statement not able to filter out the missing ids and printing out the desired 404 output response to the user

Tags: python, path, fastapi

```
my_posts = [
    {
        "title":"Title of post 1",
        "content":"content of post 1",
        "id":1
    },
    {
        "title":"Title of post 2",
        "content":"content of post 2",
        "id":2
    }
]

@app.get("/posts/{id}")
def get_post(id:int):
    for p in my_posts:
        if p['id'] == id:
            return {"data":p}
        else:
            return {"detail":"404 error, data not found"}
```

When i execute this piece of code, there is no error but the responses become faulty. Example, post 2 exists in the my_posts list which I hard coded into my program, but when I go to the route http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/2, it responds to the user returning 404 error, data not found. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your function:

1. You're iterating over the array and evaluating every item of the array and this way you will stop at the first item if that does not match, even if there are more items in your array.
2. For returning HTTP errors you have to raise a HTTPException with the status 404.

reworking your function:

```
@app.get("/posts/{id}")
def get_post(id:int):
    for p in my_posts:
        if p['id'] == id:
            return {"data":p}
    raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="data not found")
```

In this way:

1. if there is a matching id: it will return your data
2. If there is no match (so after the for loop) it will raise a HTTPException with status code 404 and the detail text.